# Cannot add NSLayoutContraints for a custom UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

At a loss for what I am doing wrong, here is my custom UIButton:

```
import UIKit

class IteratorChevronButton: UIButton {

    required init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "icon-chevron-right"), for: .normal)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Usage of IteratorChevronButton in a UIView class:

```
var btnNext: IteratorChevronButton {
    let btn = IteratorChevronButton()
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return btn
}

func doInit()  {
    self.addSubview(btnNext)

    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btnNext, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal,
                                          toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 128))
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btnNext, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal,
                                          toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 128))
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btnNext, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btnNext, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10))
}
```

I am getting the following error:
[image]

I tried to make btnNext lazy but I get the following error:

[image]

Here is the code for my custom UIView class:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import RealmSwift

enum PlayerError {
    case unknownError
}
class Player: UIView {
    let circularSliderVerticalPostionString:String = "75"
    let circularSliderWidthString:String = "180"
    let circularSliderHeightString = "180"
    var circularSliderWidth:CGFloat!
    var circularSliderHeight:CGFloat!
    let uiImageIconClose = UIImage(named: "icon-close")
    var movieDimension: CGSize = CGSize.zero
    var imageGenerator: AVAssetImageGenerator!
    var duration: CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 30)
    var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
    var avPlayer: AVPlayer!
    var startedDragging: Bool = false
    var ready: Bool = false
    var gForce: Double = 0.0
    var isInDoublePlayer:Bool = false //used as a User Runtime Define Attribute in DoublePlayerViewController.xib

    lazy var canvas: DrawingLayerView = {
       let dv = DrawingLayerView()
        return dv
    }()

    //Set this variable to swithch between normal playback and slow mo
    var playSlowMo: Bool {
        get {
            return playerToolBar.playUsingTimer
        }
        set {
            playerToolBar.playUsingTimer = newValue
        }
    }

    //This when set the playback will resume after user stop dragging... I think its worth showing to
    //some of the customers, if I were a player I would like it to be like this :)
    var continuePlaybackWhenUserStopDragging: Bool {
        get {
            return playerToolBar.autoPlayWhenStopDragging
        }
        set {
            playerToolBar.autoPlayWhenStopDragging = newValue
        }
    }

    var playbackComlete: ((_ error: PlayerError?) -> Void)? = nil

    lazy var controlBarSize: CGSize = {
        return CGSize(width: self.bounds.width*3/4, height: 100)
    }()

    lazy var playerToolBar: PlayerToolBar = {[unowned self] in
        let bar = PlayerToolBar(frame: CGRect.zero)
        bar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(bar)
        return bar
    }()

    let controlsBar: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    lazy var closeButton: UIButton = {
        let btn = ExtendedBoundsButton(type: .custom)
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        btn.setImage(self.uiImageIconClose, for: UIControlState())
        btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState())
        btn.isHidden = true
        self.addSubview(btn)
        return btn
    }()

    lazy var progressLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        return label
    }()

    var btnNext: IteratorChevronButton {
        let btn = IteratorChevronButton()
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }

    lazy var chevronImageRight: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImage(named:"icon-chevron-right")!
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return imageView
    }()

    lazy var circularSlider: BWCircularSliderView = {
        let cs = BWCircularSliderView()
        cs.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cs.frame.size.width = self.circularSliderWidth
        cs.frame.size.height = self.circularSliderHeight
        return cs
    }()

    var exporter: AVAssetExportSession? = nil
    var autoPlay: Bool = false
    var progressTimer: Timer?
    var movieDidPlay: (()->Void?)? = nil



    var onTap: (()-> Void)? 

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        doInit()
    }

    func doInit()  {
        self.circularSliderWidth = CGFloat(Int(circularSliderWidthString)!)
        self.circularSliderHeight = CGFloat(Int(circularSliderHeightString)!)
        self.addSubview(chevronImageRight)
        self.addSubview(progressLabel)
        self.addSubview(circularSlider)
        self.addSubview(btnNext)

        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btnNext, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal,
                                              toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 128))
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btnNext, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal,
                                              toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 128))
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btnNext, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
)
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btnNext, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10))

        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-\(circularSliderVerticalPostionString)-[circularSlider(\(circularSliderWidthString))]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["circularSlider": circularSlider]))
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[circularSlider(\(circularSliderHeightString))]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["circularSlider": circularSlider]))
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[toolbar(100)]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["toolbar": playerToolBar]))
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[toolbar]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["toolbar": playerToolBar]))

        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-35-[btn(40)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["btn": closeButton]))
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[btn(40)]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["btn": closeButton]))

        closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClose), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    func onClose() {
        if !ready {
            return
        }

        if let periodicTimeObserver = playerToolBar.periodicTimeObserver {
            self.avPlayer.removeTimeObserver(periodicTimeObserver)
        }
        self.avPlayer.pause()
        progressTimer?.invalidate()
        playbackComlete?(nil)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        doInit()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        playerToolBar.isInDoublePlayer = self.isInDoublePlayer
        self.circularSlider.isHidden = self.isInDoublePlayer

        self.circularSlider.gForce = self.gForce

        if let avPlayerLayer = avPlayerLayer {
            avPlayerLayer.bounds = self.bounds
            avPlayerLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width/2, y: self.bounds.height/2)

            playerToolBar.avPlayer = avPlayer
            playerToolBar.setupMovieScrollBar()
            if autoPlay {
                autoPlay = false
                play()
            }
            movieDidPlay?()
        }
        progressLabel.frame = CGRect(x: frame.size.width/2-100, y: frame.size.height/2-15, width: 200, height: 30)
        addSubview(canvas)
        addSubview(playerToolBar)
        addSubview(closeButton)
        canvas.frame = bounds
    }

    func onExportTimer(_ sender: AnyObject)  {
        guard let exporter = exporter else {
            return
        }
        progressLabel.text = "Processing " + String(Int(exporter.progress*100) ) + "%"
    }

    func mergeFiles(_ items: [String], assetWithOnset: String?,  mergeComplete: @escaping (_ fileName: String?)->Void) -> Void {
        if (assetWithOnset == nil) {
            mergeComplete(items.first!)
            return
        }
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        let track:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
        var insertTime = kCMTimeZero

        for item in items {
            let sourceAsset = AVAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: FileUtility.getPathForFileMovieDirectory(item)))
            let tracks = sourceAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
            print("\(item) \(sourceAsset.isPlayable)") // print true
            print(sourceAsset.isExportable) // print true
            print(sourceAsset.isReadable) // print true
            if tracks.count > 0 {
                let assetTrack:AVAssetTrack = tracks[0] as AVAssetTrack
                do {
                    try track.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,sourceAsset.duration), of: assetTrack, at: insertTime)
                    insertTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, sourceAsset.duration)
                } catch {
                    mergeComplete(nil)
                    return
                }
            }
        }

        let fusedFileName = "fused_" + assetWithOnset!
        let fusedFilePath = FileUtility.getPathForFileMovieDirectory(fusedFileName)
        let fusedFileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: fusedFilePath)

        do {
            //in case the file merging fails, the residual file will cause
            //the file export fail everytime as the file exist 
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: fusedFilePath)
        } catch {

        }

        exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset1280x720)
        guard let exporter = exporter  else {
            return
        }
        exporter.outputURL = fusedFileUrl
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
        progressTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(onExportTimer(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);

        exporter.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            switch exporter.status{
            case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
                if exporter.error != nil {
                    print("AVAssetExportSession failed \(exporter.error!)")
                }else{
                   print("AVAssetExportSession failed for unknown reason")
                }
                mergeComplete(nil)
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
                if exporter.error != nil {
                    print("AVAssetExportSession canceled \(exporter.error!)")
                }else{
                    print("AVAssetExportSession canceled for unknown reason")
                }
                mergeComplete(nil)
            default:

                do {
                    let realm = try Realm()
                    let movieClip = realm.object(ofType: MovieModel.self, forPrimaryKey: assetWithOnset)
                    try realm.write {
                        movieClip?.fusedFile = fusedFileName
                    }
                    //The files are released based on the usage count
                    MovieRepository.sharedInstance.release(file: movieClip?.fileName)
                    MovieRepository.sharedInstance.release(file: movieClip?.nextFile)
                    MovieRepository.sharedInstance.release(file: movieClip?.prevFile)
                } catch {

                }
                mergeComplete(fusedFileName)
                self.progressLabel.text = ""
                self.progressLabel.isHidden = true
                NotificationUtility.notifyReloadGallery()
            }
        })

    }

    func setMovies(_ items: [String], itemWithOnset asset: String?, playbackCompletion completion: @escaping ((_ error: PlayerError?) -> Void)){
        playbackComlete = completion
        closeButton.isHidden = false
        mergeFiles(items, assetWithOnset: asset ) { [weak self] (fileName) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

                if let fileName = fileName, let strongSelf = self {
                    let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: FileUtility.getPathForFileMovieDirectory(fileName)))
                    let avplayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
                    strongSelf.progressTimer?.invalidate()
                    strongSelf.progressLabel.removeFromSuperview()
                    strongSelf.duration = asset.duration
                    strongSelf.avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: avplayerItem)
                    if let playerLayer = strongSelf.avPlayerLayer {
                        playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                    }
                    strongSelf.avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: strongSelf.avPlayer)
                    strongSelf.avPlayerLayer?.zPosition = -1 //send to back
                    strongSelf.self.layer.addSublayer(strongSelf.avPlayerLayer!)


                    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(strongSelf, selector: #selector(Player.currentFileDidFinish(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: avplayerItem)
                    print("Duration \(Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(strongSelf.duration)))")
                    print("Size \(strongSelf.movieDimension)")
                    strongSelf.ready = true
                    strongSelf.autoPlay = true;
                    strongSelf.setNeedsLayout()

                }
            })

        }

    }

    func setMovie(movieAsset: MovieModel, completion: @escaping ()->Void) {

        movieDidPlay = completion
        autoPlay = true
        playerToolBar.playeBackTimer?.invalidate()
        playerToolBar.playeBackTimer = nil
        var clipNames: [String]
        var assetWithOnset: String? = nil
        if let fusedFile = movieAsset.fusedFile {
            clipNames = [fusedFile]
        } else {
            assetWithOnset = movieAsset.fileName
            if let nextFile = movieAsset.nextFile {
                clipNames = [movieAsset.prevFile!, movieAsset.fileName!, nextFile]
            } else {
                clipNames = [movieAsset.prevFile!, movieAsset.fileName!]
            }
        }
        self.setMovies(clipNames, itemWithOnset: assetWithOnset, playbackCompletion: { (err) in

        })
        closeButton.isHidden = true
    }
    func resolutionSizeForVideo(_ asset:AVAsset) -> CGSize? {
        guard let track = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).first else { return nil }
        let size = track.naturalSize.applying(track.preferredTransform)
        return CGSize(width: fabs(size.width), height: fabs(size.height))
    }
    //MARK: The playback methods
    func pause(){
        if ready {
            playerToolBar.pause()
        }
    }
    func play() {
        if ready {
            playerToolBar.play()
        }
    }

    func currentFileDidFinish(_ notification: Notification) {
    /*    if let periodicTimeObserver = playerToolBar.periodicTimeObserver {
            self.avPlayer.removeTimeObserver(periodicTimeObserver)
        }
        progressTimer?.invalidate()
        playbackComlete?(error: nil)*/

        avPlayer.seek(to: CMTimeMake(0, 30))
        avPlayer.rate = 1.0
    }

    func stop() {
        avPlayer?.pause()
        avPlayer = nil

        avPlayerLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        avPlayerLayer = nil
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
    //MARK:
}

class CollectionViewThumbNailCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    lazy var barView: UIView = {
        let lbl = UIView()
        lbl.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        lbl.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        lbl.clipsToBounds = true
        return lbl
    }()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        contentView.addSubview(barView)
    }

    func configureMark(_ big: Bool) {
        if big {
            barView.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.size.width/2 - 2, y: 2, width: 4, height: bounds.size.height)
        } else {
            barView.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.size.width/2 - 2, y: bounds.size.height/2+2, width: 4, height: bounds.size.height/2)
        }
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any logs or is it just crash?

Comment: @AhmadF just a crash, no logs...

Comment: I think you should use only constraints or only setting frames, in your superclass you are using frames and in subclass you are using constraints, moreover, you are only setting the trailing and y constraint, so its width and height is not being properly calculated

Comment: can you show some more code of your custom `UIView` class?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 ok, I have removed any frame setting and am using only constraints, still the same error, please see my updated code in my question

Comment: @AndréSlotta I have added my custom UIView class code, it is rather large, the doInit function is where I am adding constraints for my custom UIButton

Comment: try   set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints of your custom view 
 to false, after you add the button as subview.

Comment: @BrianOgden seems like you missed to create closure object for btnnext? As you have done for others. Try it same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess error is due to this (your btnNext is not being made properly):

```
var btnNext: IteratorChevronButton {
    let btn = IteratorChevronButton()
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return btn
}
```

use this syntax to make btnNext

```
var btnNext: IteratorChevronButton = {
    let btn = IteratorChevronButton()
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return btn
}()
```

Answer (score 3):

You instantiate a new button every time you access `btnNext`. So after adding one instance as a subview you use other instances for creating the constraints. Since those other subviews are no subviews of `self` the app crashes.

Make it a lazy var to instantiate it only once:

```
lazy var btnNext: IteratorChevronButton = {
    let btn = IteratorChevronButton()
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return btn
}()
```

You also have to add the `width` and `height` constraint to the button itself instead of `self`:

```
btnNext.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btnNext, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 128))
btnNext.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btnNext, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 128))
```

Update:

As *Ahmad F* stated the `lazy` keyword is totally optional in this case. You could simply instantiate your button without it if you will definitely use it:

```
var btnNext: IteratorChevronButton = {
    let btn = IteratorChevronButton()
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return btn
}()
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question, I cannot make my custom button lazy for some reason, check out my question for the error when the custom button is lazy

Comment: @BrianOgden don't forget the **=** and the trailing **()**

Comment: I think if he is pretty sure that he will he use `btnNext`, there is no reason to declare it a `lazy`.

Comment: @AhmadF True. He could use it or not. He just has to make sure that he does not create multiple instances...